# Building cob_people_detection package on Hydro

Tags: ros, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently running Ros Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to use a Kinect for face recognition.

I found the [cob_people_detection](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection) package and downloaded [cob_people_perception-hydro_dev](https://github.com/ipa-rmb/cob_people_perception/tree/hydro_dev) to my catkin_ws/src/ folder, but when I try to build it with catkin_make I get errors concerning several configuration files, like this ones:

*CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package cob_image_flip.*

*CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package cob_perception_msgs.*

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Athria/1922fc4250ed95e944fb) is the complete log.

I tried deleting the devel and build folders, and then building, but I get the same error. I don't have a similar problem with any of the other packages I'm using, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.

Thank you in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208564/building-cob_people_detection-package-on-hydro/) by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, now I could read your log and figured out what is the problem. In addition to the cob_people_perception repository (most recent version from here: https://github.com/ipa-rmb/cob_people_perception) you need to have the cob_perception_common repository. This one might be released already (i.e. can be installed via sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-cob-perception-common) but we are not releasing the latest versions on hydro anymore. Hence I suppose that even if you would have installed cob_perception_common, your version is outdated.

Please download the newest hydro version of cob_perception_common from https://github.com/ipa-rmb/cob_perception_common and try to compile again.

Please notice that we will not implement future features into the hydro_dev branch anymore. For now it appeared that the indigo_dev version is working with ROS hydro successfully. So you might also give the indigo_dev branches a chance (hydro_dev and indigo_dev should be similar at the moment).

Best regards,
Richard

---

Originally posted by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) with karma: 36 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-08**:
Hello, thank you very much for your answer, I installed the missing cob_perception_common package for ros hydro and reinstalled the perception package, but I'm still getting errors, this time concerning mostly missing headers (https://gist.github.com/Athria/141e5fc30a4748009cfb) in lines 66, 72, etc

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-08**:
I also tried installing the indigo_dev like suggested, but it threw errors as well. I think I have all the dependencies for the openni2_tracker and I couldn't find anything about additional dependencies for the libnite2, but from the errors I think I might be missing something there. Thank you again

**Comment by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) on 2015-05-08**:
The errors originate from missing messages. You may solve the problem by just using one core for compilation (i.e. "catkin_make -j1") or by running catkin_make several times until everything compiles. Anyways, I have (hopefully) fixed the dependencies now, just pull and build the software again.

**Comment by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) on 2015-05-08**:
Background: Catkin requires to add a line "add_dependencies(${p} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)" to run message generation from other packages before building this package when using multiple cores. I have fixed that in the hydro_dev and indigo_dev branches now.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-11**:
Hello, sorry but it is still trowing errors when I tried to build (https://gist.github.com/Athria/c575b2178a3b13c0e29b), first I downloaded again both packages from github and tried with catkin_make and catkin_make -j1, since none of them worked and I couldn't fix the error I tried deleting (1/2)

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-11**:
other packages to see if it made any difference (I once had an issue with two conflicting packages), but it didn't help. Today I downloaded the common and perception packages once more and compiled several times, but it's still the same error. I tried deleting the devel and build folders too (2/2)

**Comment by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) on 2015-05-13**:
Looks like a SSL problem when downloading and md5sum checking sources of a library to build. You might try out two things:

1. Open file  cob_people_perception/libnite2/Makefile.tarball and comment line 8 (MD5SUM_FILE = NiTE-Linux-x64-2.2.tar.bz2.md5sum) out by putting a # before it (#MD5SUM_FILE...

**Comment by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) on 2015-05-13**:
2 Just ignore those packages that give you trouble by putting an empty file with name "CATKIN_IGNORE" into the respective  main folders. You do not need the following packages: libnite2,  cob_people_tracking_filter, cob_openni2_tracker, cob_leg_detection. You may put CATKIN_IGNORE in all of them.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-16**:
Thank you very much, with the first suggestion the compilation errors remained, but ignoring the packages you mentioned in the second one it compiled without errors. Thank you again.

**Comment by [ipa-rmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/22363/ipa-rmb/) on 2015-05-19**:
Wonderful :-)